# Git svn fetch check if no commit left to merge

Tags: git-svn, git-merge, git-fetch

I have cloned a svn project repo using git-svn. When I fetch commits, how do I check that there are no commits to be merged left for all  branches from the fetch I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, for a given branch, diff between the HEAd of that branch and what you have fetched:

```
git diff ..remotes/git-svn
```

or if you just want the file names:

```
git diff ..remotes/git-svn --name-status
```

with, as an example, `git-svn` the name of the remote svn repo.

Comment: Thanks VonC, just what I needed.